# Understanding panzoom in Vue

Tags: javascript, zooming

I'm trying to understand how zooming works. I use Vue and the [panzoom](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom) project.
I found out that I can use the smoothZoom function in order to zoom. But I struggle to understand which parameters it should get.

From chrome I see that I can use the following function of `panzoom`

```
ƒ smoothZoom(clientX, clientY, scaleMultiplier) {
      var fromValue = transform.scale
      var from = {scale: fromValue}
      var to = {scale: scaleMultiplier * fromValue}
```

But I don't understand what is the purpose of `clientX, clientY, scaleMultiplier`.
For now, I use the function as following:

```
var transform = this.newArea.getTransform();
var deltaX = transform.x;
var deltaY = transform.y;
var scale = transform.scale;
var newScale = scale + this.minScale; // minScale is set to 0.2
this.newArea.smoothZoom(deltaX,deltaY,newScale);
```

But for some reason it does not zoom as expected, it could zoom in left, zoom in right, even zoom out.
I create `newArea` as following:

```
const area = document.querySelector('.chart');
this.newArea = panzoom(area, { maxZoom: this.maxZoom, minZoom: this.minZoom, zoomSpeed: this.zoomSpeed });
```

I think that I don't fully understand the meaning of the arguments and probably my algorithm does not work.
How should I change the `deltaX`, `deltaY` and `newScale` so it work (I mean which arguments should I pass)?

Comment: Not really related to Vue. Adjusted tags accordingly

Comment: @StephenThomas Thank you

Comment: @TTaJTa4 can you use [vue-svg-pan-zoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-svg-pan-zoom). If you want I can prepare a demo for you

Answer (score 1):

**Okay maybe i missunderstood the issue:**

so the [`smoothZoom`](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom/blob/301682fd37f0c2af84690bf423b1443f0dbc7136/index.js#L723) method actually calls [amator](https://github.com/anvaka/amator)

this then calls for each timedelta within the growth from the current `scale` to `scale * scaleMultiplier`, `({scale}) => zoomAbs(clientX, clientY, scale)`

zoomAbs then calculates the ratio and calls zoomRatio wich asigns transform x,y and scale and triggers callbacks and lastly calls [applyTransform](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom/blob/301682fd37f0c2af84690bf423b1443f0dbc7136/index.js#L444)

clientX, clientY will be calculated by [transformToScreen](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom/blob/301682fd37f0c2af84690bf423b1443f0dbc7136/index.js#L163) and passed to transform,

but I suggest to read the source to get a deeper insight

scaleMultiplier is the multiplier for the zoom.

<strike>**Short**</strike>

deltax does css `translate-x`

deltay does css `translate-y`

scale does css `scale`

**Insight**

*Panzoom* uses css transform matrices: [`applyTransform`](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom/blob/master/lib/domController.js#L41)

and as per readable specs: [`matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix)

where in the used variance:

- `a` is the scalefactor in x direction
- `b` is `0`
- `c` is `0`
- `d` is the scalefactor in y direction
- `tx` is the translation in x direction
- `ty` is the translation in y direction

for a deeper knowledge one can just calculate some examples:

Given a shape with point A, B, C, D.
Now for any valid transformmatrix M the resulting points A', B', C', D' are calculated this way:

M x A = A' (to not violate math A will be (0,0,1,1) so 4x4 times 4x1)

...

M x D = D'

so in detail for A = (x,y,1,1):

- A'.x = A.x * a + A.y * c + 1 * 0 + 1 * tx,

and with c = 0:

- A'.x = A.x * a + tx,

analog:

- A'.y = A.x * b + A.y * d + 1 * 0 + 1 * ty,

and with b = 0:

- A'.y = A.y * d + ty

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.changed {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>Normal</div>
<div class="changed">Changed</div>
```

Comment: I think you should add on how to use the `panzoom` project in order to zoomIn and zoomOut (because that is what the OP asked).